# MySQL: Intersect in the same table

Tags: mysql, inner-join, intersect

Hard to describe it in the title alone.
Assume we have 3 tables: one with students, one with teachers, and a third one called teaching where each student gets associated to their teachers like this:

```
+------+------+
| s_id | t_id |
+------+------+
| s1   | t1   |
+------+------+
| s1   | t2   |
+------+------+
| s1   | t3   |
+------+------+
| s2   | t1   |
+------+------+
| s2   | t2   |
+------+------+
| s2   | t4   |
+------+------+
```

In this example, student s1 has teachers t1, t2 and t3, while student s2 has teachers t1, t2, and t4.

Now the problem: given the two students s1 and s2, how many teachers do they have in common?
Answer is 2 (t1 and t2).

```
+------+
| t1   |
+------+
| t2   |
+------+
```

Now I don't know how to do that with a query. Intersect didn't work and after trying an inner join of the table with itself I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with a subquery like this :

```
SELECT t_id FROM teaching WHERE s_id = 's1'
AND t_id IN
(SELECT t_id FROM teaching WHERE s_id = 's2');
```

You could also use an inner join like this (demo below is updated):

```
SELECT t1.t_id FROM teaching t1
INNER JOIN teaching t2 ON (t1.t_id = t2.t_id)
WHERE t1.s_id = 's1' AND t2.s_id = 's2'
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1769/11)

Comment: The performance is not great, but it's working. I guess it's a limitation of RDBMS and I should maybe use another database type.

Comment: I have added another solution which may be better in terms of performance

Answer (score 0):

So the following query works:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM teaching 
WHERE s_id = "s1" 
AND t_id IN (SELECT t_id FROM teaching WHERE s_id = "s2")
```

but the performance is terrible, it takes about 7-8s with just a sample of the database

Answer (score 0):

You can try as bellow

```
SELECT t.t_id 
FROM teaching AS t
INNER JOIN teaching AS t1 ON t.t_id = t1.t_id AND t1.s_id = 's2'
WHERE t.s_id = 's1'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6be321f/14

Comment: The performance is about the same, but since performance is out of scope of this thread, it's effectively solved